# d3.js: Converting Months to Quarter

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, nested

I'm trying to convert a csv with data in months format to quarter format (avg for quarter, not sum..)

The output I need is a nested array, as shown below for the months, only for quarters. I've already calculated each quarter for month using the d3.nest function, but I can't seem to get it converted to quarters.

Here is the csv with the data:

```
x,January,February,March,April,May,June,July
Overall,3635,3371,3474,4212,4815,5544,4464
A,1689,1489,1588,2231,2419,2889,2304
B,316,266,267,323,337,354,435
C,622,537,629,614,766,720,616
```

Here is the code that nests the data:

```
nest = d3.nest().key(function(d) { return d.x; })
                        .rollup(function(leaves) { var a = []; d3.entries(leaves[0]).forEach(function (k) { if (k.key != "x") a.push({x: k.key, y: k.value, month: k.key, quater: (Math.floor((new Date(Date.parse(k.key + "1, 2013")).getMonth()+1)/3+1))}); }); return a; });
data = nest.entries(data);
```

Which results in (stipped to fit..):

```
[
   {
      "key":"Overall",
      "values":[
         {
            "x":"January",
            "y":"3635",
            "month":"January",
            "quater":1
         },
         {
            "x":"February",
            "y":"3371",
            "month":"February",
            "quater":1
         },
         {
            "x":"March",
            "y":"3474",
            "month":"March",
            "quater":2
         },
         {
            "x":"April",
            "y":"4212",
            "month":"April",
            "quater":2
         },
         {
            "x":"May",
            "y":"4815",
            "month":"May",
            "quater":2
         },
         {
            "x":"June",
            "y":"5544",
            "month":"June",
            "quater":3
         },
         {
            "x":"July",
            "y":"4464",
            "month":"July",
            "quater":3
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "key":"A",
      "values":[
         {
            "x":"January",
            "y":"1689",
            "month":"January",
            "quater":1
         },
         {
            "x":"February",
            "y":"1489",
            "month":"February",
            "quater":1
         },
         {
            "x":"March",
            "y":"1588",
            "month":"March",
            "quater":2
         },
         {
            "x":"April",
            "y":"2231",
            "month":"April",
            "quater":2
         },
         {
            "x":"May",
            "y":"2419",
            "month":"May",
            "quater":2
         },
         {
            "x":"June",
            "y":"2889",
            "month":"June",
            "quater":3
         },
         {
            "x":"July",
            "y":"2304",
            "month":"July",
            "quater":3
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "key":"B",
      "values":[
         {
            "x":"January",
            "y":"316",
            "month":"January",
            "quater":1
         },
         {
            "x":"February",
            "y":"266",
            "month":"February",
            "quater":1
         },
         {
            "x":"March",
            "y":"267",
            "month":"March",
            "quater":2
         },
         {
            "x":"April",
            "y":"323",
            "month":"April",
            "quater":2
         },
         {
            "x":"May",
            "y":"337",
            "month":"May",
            "quater":2
         },
         {
            "x":"June",
            "y":"354",
            "month":"June",
            "quater":3
         },
         {
            "x":"July",
            "y":"435",
            "month":"July",
            "quater":3
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "key":"C",
      "values":[
         {
            "x":"January",
            "y":"622",
            "month":"January",
            "quater":1
         },
         {
            "x":"February",
            "y":"537",
            "month":"February",
            "quater":1
         },
         {
            "x":"March",
            "y":"629",
            "month":"March",
            "quater":2
         },
         {
            "x":"April",
            "y":"614",
            "month":"April",
            "quater":2
         },
         {
            "x":"May",
            "y":"766",
            "month":"May",
            "quater":2
         },
         {
            "x":"June",
            "y":"720",
            "month":"June",
            "quater":3
         },
         {
            "x":"July",
            "y":"616",
            "month":"July",
            "quater":3
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Thanks in advance for the helpers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you loading the CSV using d3.csv?  If so, your current data transformation can be done without d3.nest().  Then d3.nest() can be used to rollup by quarter.  Here's an example:

```
d3.csv('data.csv', function(row) {
  var key = row.x;
  var entries = d3.entries(row);

  // remove the first (the x column)
  entries.shift();

  // map the rest of the columns
  entries = entries.map(function(entry) {
    return {
      value: entry.value,
      month: entry.key,
      quarter: (Math.floor((new Date(Date.parse(entry.key + "1, 2013")).getMonth()+1)/3+1)) 
    };
  });


  // nest the array of months by quarter, rollup to return the mean
  var quarters = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return +d.quarter; })
    .rollup(function(d) { return d3.mean(d, function(d){ return +d.value; })})
    .entries(entries);

  var months = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.month; })
    .rollup(function(d) { return d3.sum(d, function(d) { return +d.value; })})
    .entries(entries);

  // return object for this row 
  return {
    key: row.x,
    months: months,
    quarters: quarters
  };
}, function(data) {
  /* at this point data is an array of objects like: 
    {
     key: 'Overall', 
     months: [{key: January, values: 123} ....],
     quarters: [{key: 1, values: 4322}, ....]
    }
  */ 

  console.log(data);
});
```

**UPDATE**
This will return a single array, each entry having a months and a quarters array.  In your visualization code, you could just pull from the appropriate months or quarters property dynamically.

Plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/sVt0T5LrTFJkMiVpkk8F?p=preview

Comment: I am using d3.csv, and it seems like we have a solution! Thanks for compiling this.  Once thing though, the output I'm looking for is having 2 arrays seperated for the months and quarters, meaning arr1= [{key: "Overall", values: months... }, {key:... }] and arr2= [{key: "Overall", values: quarters... }, {key: ... }] <--- what would be the best way to accomplish that? I know the simple way, simply running through the array in the callback function and creating 2 additional arrays, but I guess that's not very efficient.

Comment: I've updated so that the months and quarters arrays are in the same format, if you really want two separate arrays you'd probably need to iterate through them to create two arrays.  But by being in the same format, it will be easier to reuse the code in your visualization.